# Call method in Web Api

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

I have a method in my `itemsController` in my Web Api:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetItemGroups()
        {
            return repository.GetAllItems()
                                   .Select(p => p.Group)
                                   .Distinct();
        }
```

This method is supposed to return all the unique values of a column on a csv file. It build fine, but how to I call this method?

To get the,

- **full list of items** I use `localhost:12345/api/items`
- for an **item by an id** I use `localhost:12345/items/2`

How do I call the method `GetItemGroups` ?

Comment: See judder's answer below. Right now, you have ambiguous routes, because the URI for GetItemGroups is also /api/items. (I'm assuming that you're using the default Web API route created by the project template.)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Attribute Routing](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting/) nuget package. This allows you to specify the urls you want for each action. The documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting)

Comment: Also attribute routing has been added to Web API 2.